# Construct a group using two elements $a$ and $b$ which satisfy the relation $a^2=b^2=e$, where $e$ is the identity.

Tags: group-theory

I am  stuck with a problem in which I have been asked to construct a group using two elements $a$ and $b$ which satisfy the relation $a^2=b^2=e$... (i), where $e$ is the identity. The elements that surely belong to the group are $e, a, b, ab$ ($a, b$ being their own inverse). Somehow my intuition says that there is a trick by which I can show that it's an abelian group. what I have tried doing is writing using (i) that $a=b^2$$a^{-1}$, but this didn't work, What can I do now? Is this group abelian?
(This problem is not a part of a graded assignment that I am supposed to turn in. )

Comment: The answer to this question is not unique. One possibility is that the group is abelian and has exactly four elements $\{e,a,b,ab\}$. But there  are also nonabelian groups satisfying these conditions, namely the dihedral groups in which $a$ and $b$ are both reflections.

Comment: There exist non abelian groups still checking the property you are asking. Namely, you can consider the free product $\mathbb{Z}_2\ast\mathbb{Z}_2=\langle a,b|a^2=b^2=e\rangle$ which elements are words using the letters $a$ and $b$ such that consecutive $a$ or $b$ cancel out. You can check that the words $ab$ and $ba$ are different ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All groups satisfying the conditions will each be a quotient of the [free product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product)

$$\Bbb Z_2\ast\Bbb Z_2\cong \langle a,b\mid a^2=b^2=e\rangle.\tag{1}$$

The RHS of $(1)$ is what is known as a [group presentation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group).

Answer (score 2):

Going by the wording , it seems that this is the (minimal) group :

$\{a=e,b\}$

The closed binary operation $+$ is :

$a+a=a$
$a+b=b$
$b+a=b$
$b+b=a$

We can see that $a^2=b^2=a=e$

Alternately , we can try this :

$\{a,b=e\}$

The closed binary operation $+$ is :

$a+a=b$
$a+b=a$
$b+a=a$
$b+b=b$

We can then see that this is Exactly Same , we have renamed $(a,b)$ to $(b,a)$

Comment: No, $b$ could be the identity too.

Comment: Yes , @Shaun , it will be isomorphic to the one I have listed.

Comment: No, the group you describe is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: I mean: *both* $a$ and $b$ can be the identity, so what you describe is not minimal.

Comment: OP wants group with 2 elements , hence we can not have $a=b=e$ , @Shaun , hence this is the minimal.

Comment: Fair enough. ${}$

Comment: Meanwhile , someone who follows the herd decided to follow the existing Downvote , & that someone may never come back to check , oh well !